# JPA and server time zone error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

No matter what I do to change the time zone in either phpmyadmin or the connectionstring in persistence.xml I get this error:

```
 com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: 
 The server time zone value 'Romance Summer Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. 
 You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="booking" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/_boekingdb_/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Adding

```
?useUnicode=true&amp;useJD‌​BCCompliantTimezoneS‌​hift=true&amp;useLeg‌​acyDatetimeCode=fals‌​e&amp;serverTimezone‌​=UTC"
```

to the jdbc.url connectionstring does nothing

I don't even have a clue where this 'Romance Summer Time' is coming from.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding

```
default-time-zone=+00:00
```

to my.ini (in xamp\mysql\bin) fixed everything...

Answer (score 0):

Added `serverTimezone=UTC` to

```xml
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/_boekingdb_/>
```

and it works fine.  The result is

```xml
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/_boekingdb_/?serverTimezone=UTC>
```